# Trying to convert sync event to async, getting error Expression denotes a `method group', where a `variable', `value' or `type' was expected

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

Note: This is C# in Xamarin Studio

I am trying to convert my currently synchronous method into an asynchronous one as the method triggered by the TouchUpInside event calls a second method in a different class that does a REST call which can take up to 45 seconds to complete.

Problem I am getting the error

> Expression denotes a 'method group', where a 'variable', 'value' or `type' was expected

on the line

```
btnStartIdCheck.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => await runIDCheckCameraProcess;
```

I am new to threading and this has completely flummoxed me...

The documentation from https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/ is where I initially started and then tried various solutions on SoF such as [The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593501/the-await-operator-can-only-be-used-within-an-async-lambda-expression) and [I'm trying to turn a synchronous method from some old code into an asynchronous method, but I'm having some trouble understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166486/converting-a-method-to-use-async) without much difference in my errors other than suggestions by intellisense telling me ensure my lambda was marked with the async keyword.

**ViewController Class** (paired down for brevity)

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;
using Performance_Shared;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Performance
{
    partial class VCIDCheck : UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            btnStartIdCheck.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => await runIDCheckCameraProcess;

            // Lambda attempt gives same error on enclosed await
            // btnStartIdCheck.TouchUpInside += async delegate {
            //   await runIDCheckCameraProcess;
            // };

            btnCloseIdCheck.TouchUpInside += btnCancelCloseTheWindow;
        }

        private async Task<bool> runIDCheckCameraProcess (Object sender, EventArgs ea) 
        {
            //...Omitted code to run camera, take photo, save to private folder etc...

                json_IDCheck postIDCheckData = new json_IDCheck();

                // Do REST call to remote server, this is the async call
                // 'postIDCheckData' is a Class holding some data that is passed to API

                DruidRest druidPostIDCheck = new DruidRest(SingletonAppSettngs.Instance ().baseApiUri);
                jsonIDCheckRequestStatus requestStatus = druidPostIDCheck.postIDCheck (postIDCheckData);

                // ...Do some more stuff with the response...
        }
    }
}
```

**DruidRest Class** showing only the postIDCheck method

```
namespace Performance_Shared
{
    public class DruidRest : IDruidRest
    {

        public DruidRest (string api_url)
        {
            this.apiBaseUrl = api_url;
        }

        public Task<jsonIDCheckRequestStatus> postIDCheckAsync(json_IDCheck idCheckData)
        {
            jsonIDCheckRequestStatus jsonIDCheckStatus = new jsonIDCheckRequestStatus ();
            jsonIDCheckStatus.div_check_status = "Completed";
            jsonIDCheckStatus.ErrorMessage = null;

            return Task.Factory.StartNew (() =>
            {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    return jsonIDCheckStatus;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just missing brackets behind that medhod...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runIDCheckCameraProcess` is a method - to call it, you must use parentheses and supply the necessary parameters.  If the method does not actually use the two parameters, then you can probably just pass null.

```
btnStartIdCheck.TouchUpInside += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => await runIDCheckCameraProcess(null,null);
```

This is a common C# error - it really has nothing to do with async/await.

Comment: Thanks Jason, bang on.